# Creating DOM elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say we have the following JavaScript/jQuery code below

```
function createElement(i, value) {
    return $('<div>', { id: "field" + i, text: value});
}
```

I have a div with an id of "container" and then I do:

```
var c=$("container");
c.append(createElement(1, "hello, world!");
```

Now I've got 2 questions

1. Does the createElement function use jQuery to return an HTML string that gets appended to container or does it dynamically create a DOM element that gets appended to the container?
2. I'm unfamiliar with this kind of jQuery where you actually create the HTML string (or DOM element) via the $() selector. I tried looking for the documentation on this subject in jQuery's website but I couldn't find it. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: should probably be `<div />` to have a properly closed div

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. It creates the DOM element on the fly, and appends that.
2. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll approve this answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 6):

1. In fact it creates the DOM element + it returns a jQuery object which contains your DOM element you just created.
2. Dogbert was right about this, [the doc is here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery#jQuery-html-props)